# fgets not scanning second time through while loop C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, fgets

So i made this program to scan for an address and then ask the uesr if they want o insert another one or print the ones already inserted. When i run it i goes through it once then what ever i insert for &y it prints a random number then prints the line with the comment in it again and scans for &y. I feel like its skipping the fgets function the second time through the do-while loop. Help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>



int main (void)
{

    char address[10][100];
        int x;
    char y;

    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
         do {
           printf("Enter address %d:", x + 1); //prints this second time through

           fgets(address[x], 100, stdin); //doesnt scan for this second time through

           printf("Do you want to print address's inserted thus far or continue?(p or c):"); // prints this second time through also. 

            scanf("%d" , &y);

            if (y == "c") continue;

            else

               printf("%d" , &y);
               break;

    } while (strcmp(address[x], "\n") == 0);
}















return(0);  
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the error messages the compiler is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` holds the newline character of your input, and adds a NULL character.
Try changing your value 100 by 99, for example, in order to make some room.

If your input (including newline) has more than 99 characters, then you need to 'flush' the input by reading dummy characters until newline is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
        if (y == "c") continue;

        else

           printf("%d" , &y);
           break;
```

is mis-indented.  The `break;` *is* executed after the `printf()` (and not after the `continue;`), but technically, the code is equivalent to:

```
        if (y == "c")
            continue;
        else
            printf("%d" , &y);
        break;
```

However, your primary problem is that `scanf("%d", &y);` leaves the newline in the input stream, so the next `fgets()` reads the newline, and stops. Also, since `y` is a `char`, you should be using `scanf("%c", &y);` to read the value and `if (y == 'c')` to compare it.

Comment: Suggest `(" %c", &y);` and fix `(y == "c")`.  I gave-up on this post.

Comment: Yeah; good points.  The space in front of the `%c` is not immediately critical, but the comparison should be a compiler warning, if not error, and ... giving up seems appropriate.

Comment: there is a compiler warning talking about comparison between pointers is this some how related? How can i fix this?

Comment: @user3521465: Yes; we should be using `y == 'c'` instead of `y == "c"`.  Regard all warnings from the compiler as an error on your part, especially if you've not added any 'please warn more' flags.